# Swagger Nest.js ValidationPipe ApiBadRequestResponse

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger, documentation, nestjs

I just started playing around with Swagger and everything is amazing. I was able to document all API in an hour or so but I got stuck solving one last issue.

How can I tell swagger to show `ApiBadRequestResponse` in the format below?

```
@ApiOkResponse({
  type: User,
})
@ApiBadRequestResponse({
  type: {
    error: String,
    message: ValidationError[]
  }
})
@Post('/signup')
signUp(
  @Body(ValidationPipe) authCredentialsDto: CredentialsDTO
): Promise<User> {
  return this.userService.signUp(authCredentialsDto)
}
```

From what I understand swagger doesn't know how to work with interfaces instead I have to use classes. Is there a simple way to document bad request response triggered by `ValidationPipe`. This is all native `@nestjs` behavior so I would assume there must be an easy solution.

This is what gets actually returned from API:

```
"statusCode": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": [
  {
    "target": {
      "username": "somename",
      "password": "****"
    },
    "value": "****",
    "property": "password",
    "children": [], // ValidationError[]
    "constraints": {
      "matches": "password too weak"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. `ValidationError` is an interface exposed by `class-validator` which there's nothing NestJS can do about it being an interface. I have an idea but it doesn't fully address your issue. https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger#raw-definitions maybe try this or raise an issue in `nestjs/swagger` github

Comment: Could you please show me how to define the answer using raw definitions? I think when the type has to be 'array' or Class. (no need for recursive children type)

Comment: I still haven’t figured out how to use raw definitions for recursive (children).

Comment: And as I said, if you could raise an issue, we might be able to do something. I am thinking about exposing a way to add a arbitrary Schema which later can be used in Raw Definitions by something else. In your case, you can have a recursive schema (not recursive raw def)

Comment: And without recursive schema? I had a similar problem with a response that just returned `{ accessToken: string }`. I had to create a class in order to define the response. I don't think it is possible with plain objects. I will create Issue on GitHub by the end of the day.

Comment: With that you can have: ApiResponse({ schema: {type: ‘object’, properties: { accessToken: { type: ‘string’ } } } })

Comment: https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/571

Comment: @ChauTran If you turn your comment into an answer I will accept it :)